# pandas python 3.9 object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

simple code works under python 3.8 but raise error under 3.9.

the pandas `series.mean()` raise the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odin/Learn/Udemy/python_100/day_25/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(data["temp"].mean())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 11118, in mean
    return NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 10726, in mean
    return self._stat_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 10711, in _stat_function
    return self._reduce(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4182, in _reduce
    return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 71, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 124, in f
    result = bn_func(values, axis=axis, **kwds)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("weather_data_n.csv")
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None): 
    print(data)
temp_list = data["temp"].to_list()
print(data["temp"].mean())
```

Comment: Your error message means that `bn_func == None`

Comment: Can you show the `print(data)`? maybe just `print(data.head()`?

Comment: If there was no `data["temp"]` this would have failed with a KeyError, which would make sense. The error you get is not very informative. It might be some weird unhandled edge case in pandas. In any case we cannot give you an answer without your data.